# Is this a correct proof for this limit?

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Prove that the sequence $3+\frac{2}{n^2}$ converges to 3.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then:

$\left | 3+\frac{2}{n^2}-3 \right |=\left | \frac{2}{n^2} \right |=\frac{2}{n^2}<\epsilon$

Thus, $n>\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}$

We may choose $n(\epsilon)=\sqrt{\left \lceil  \frac{2}{\epsilon} \right \rceil} \in\mathbb{N}$. In conclusion, for all $n>n(\epsilon)=\sqrt{\left \lceil  \frac{2}{\epsilon} \right \rceil}$ we have:

$\left | 3+\frac{2}{n^2}-3 \right |=\left | \frac{2}{n^2} \right |=\frac{2}{n^2}<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

You've definitely gotten the idea, but your proof could be cleaned up a bit. Let me walk you through how I would solve this problem.

First, as scratch work (not as part of the proof), I would write

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 |3 + \frac{2}{n^2} - 3| < \epsilon &\to |\frac{2}{n^2}| < \epsilon \\
&\to \frac{2}{n^2} < \epsilon \\
&\to n > \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Then, I would proceed with the proof as follows:

Consider some $\epsilon > 0$. Take some natural number $N$ such that $N \geq \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}$ - such an $N$ exists by the Archimedean property. I claim that for all $n > N$, we have $|3 + \frac{2}{n^2} - 3| < \epsilon$.

For consider some such $n > N$. Then we have $n > \sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}} > 0$. Since the function $x \mapsto x^2$ is increasing for positive $x$, we have $n^2 > (\sqrt{\frac{2}{\epsilon}})^2 = \frac{2}{\epsilon}$. Therefore, $\frac{2}{n^2} < \epsilon$. Then $|3 - \frac{2}{n^2} - 3| = |\frac{2}{n^2}| = \frac{2}{n^2} < \epsilon$, as required.

Therefore, we see that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 3 + \frac{2}{n^2} = 3$. $\square$

Note the following differences between your approach and my approach.

First, don't try to hard to exactly state the specific $N$ you're coming up with. Your approach actually doesn't always give us a natural number since you took the ceiling function in the wrong place. Instead, just state that $N$ is larger than some real value.

Second, don't include the "scratch work" as part of the official proof. Scratch work is important for deriving the answer, but it only distracts from the proof.

Comment: Nice pedagogy.  And congratulations on reaching 15k.

Comment: @RobertShore Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. The reason I included the scratch work in the proof is that in my country for some reason professors do that as well so they require it.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost correct, but $\sqrt{\left\lceil\frac2\varepsilon\right\rceil}$ doesn't have to be a natural number. You can take $\left\lceil\sqrt{\frac2\varepsilon}\,\right\rceil$ instead.